# ObjectListView doesn't word-wrap

Tags: c#, word-wrap, ownerdrawn, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView instead of the standard ListView is because I wanted to word-wrap the columns.

I read in several places that the only thing I need to to in order to enable word-wrapping is the set `column.wordWrap` to true.

I did just that, but it doesn't work.

What am I missing here?

**Edit:**
I realise now that I need to make my column owner drawn.
I found [this page](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/cookbook-ownerdraw.htm) which sort of tells me what to do, but I'm not sure where to place it in my code. I'm also not quite sure whether I need to add certain attributes inside the delegate to allow word-wrapping (by the looks opf things it's enabled by default). The thing is, I tried what I found in this page, copied it word for word, and my list looks exactly the same...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? Edit your question to include code and screenshots of what you have currently, and how you expected it to look.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean by "word wrapping", you want different rows to have different heights, the FAQ answer is correct -- it simply can't be done.

However, if you make each row so that it can display two or more lines of text, then, yes, `ObjectListView` can word wrap.

It needs three conditions:

1. Set `WordWrap` to *true* on the column to wrap. You've already done that.
2. Make sure the `ObjectListView` is owner drawn (set `OwnerDraw` to *true* -- this can be done in the Form Designer). The base `ListView` can't word wrap, so we have to draw the cells ourself.
3. Make sure there is room to see the wrapped lines by setting the RowHeight to 32 (or some other value)

This is the data tab from the demo. The first column has `WordWrap` set to true.
[image: Word wrap in action]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do, and I have set the RowHeight to 32 and it still didn't work, so I guess what I'm missing is the second condition.
How do I make sure it is indeed owner drawn?

Answer (score 0):

On the [ObjectListView SourceForge FAQ](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/faq.htm) page, it explicitly states:

> Can it word-wrap?
>
> No.

Comment: You have to read the whole paragraph. The NO refers to "Can an ObjectListView have rows of different heights?". Its not the problem, that the text can't be wrapped. The problem is, that the row high would have to be increased for ALL rows to display it properly.